# Login with my organization Google account with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

Is it possible to limit my endpoints api to my organization's Google accounts?

P.D.

I do not have access to the Administrator account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could protect your API method by injecting the `User` object. Now, when the API Method is invoked, you can check for the User object and get the Email Addresses and Authenticating Domain to perform your check and move ahead in your API Method.